# Passing a mixed form made by HTML and jQuery to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im making a sort of game auction house for a school project. I combine html and jquery to make a form. The form input has to be send to a database with php. In the code I have an if statement in php, but it seems to always be false (even if I empty the whole forms and just place the button + the hidden input which I use in the form tags).

```
<form class="add_item" name="add_item" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"> 
    <input type='hidden' name='add_item_b' id='add_item_b' value='true' />
    <input type='button' name='add_item_but' value='Add Item'>
</form>
```

Code can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vN7LQ/

And i think im going to need ajax? How would i implement this in this mixed form of html and jQuery code?

Comment: Did you bother doing ANY basic debugging, e.g. check `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is actually being submitted?

Comment: thanks for the answer marc B, i tried a lot of debugging options but it just doesnt seem to send, even when the button is scriptedin the main html file

Comment: I see no submit button? Like Marc B suggest, do a `vardump`

Comment: Thanh Trung, thanks for the answer. the JS isnt properly called in the jsfiddle file, i dont know why but it is there at my localhost

Comment: I already debugged it, but i really cant find what is wrong

Comment: Where is the form submit button?

Comment: $('#item_info').append(" <input type='hidden' name='add_item_b' id='add_item_b' value='true' /> ");
   $('#item_info').append(" <input type='button' name='add_item_but' value='Add Item'><br>");